# update nested object in react context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I want Update nested object in react context api

this is my context

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
const TeethInfoContext = createContext();

export function TeethInfoProvider({ children }) {
  const [teethInfo, setTeethInfo] = useState({
    11: {
      mesial: true,
      distal: false,
      incisal: false,
    },
  12: {
      mesial: true,
      distal: false,
      incisal: false,
    },
  13: {
      mesial: true,
      distal: false,
      incisal: false,
    },


  return (
    <TeethInfoContext.Provider
      value={{ teethInfo, cordinates, drawShape, setTeethInfo }}
    >
      {children}
    </TeethInfoContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default TeethInfoContext;
```

how can update single value in this object like {11: mesial } set to false

thanks

i tried many ways to update

tried this function in children

```
 function drawMesial() {
   
   setTeethInfo({ ...teethInfo, mesial: teethInfo[11].mesial });
}
```

not working

and tried

```
function drawShape(param, id) {
     setTeethInfo({ ...teethInfo, param: !teethInfo[id].param });
  }
```

in context but didnt work

Comment: There is no key named `param` in your objects, so your second one won't work. (Technically, it creates `param` but doesn't change `mesial`. Your first one is too complicated. If you want to set something to false, just do it: `mesial: false`.

Answer (score 1):

The [React documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state) suggests using an updater function to change the state based on the previous state.

```js
setTeethInfo((teethInfo) => {
  let teethInfoTemp = teethInfo;
  teethInfoTemp[11].mesial = false;
  return teethInfoTemp;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new function to update the values but be careful with the mutability.

Looks here:

- https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data
- https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-objects-and-arrays-in-state

```
function updateTeethInfo(teethId, key, value) {
  setTeethInfo(prevInfo => ({
    ...prevInfo,
    [teethId]: {
      ...prevInfo[teethId],
      [key]: value
    }
  }));
}
```

To set `{11: mesial}` to false, you would call:

```
updateTeethInfo(11, 'mesial', false);
```

Here is what the code will look like.

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const TeethInfoContext = createContext();

export function TeethInfoProvider({ children }) {
  const [teethInfo, setTeethInfo] = useState({
    11: { mesial: true, distal: false, incisal: false },
    12: { mesial: true, distal: false, incisal: false },
    13: { mesial: true, distal: false, incisal: false },
  });

  function updateTeethInfo(teethId, key, value) {
    setTeethInfo(prevInfo => ({
      ...prevInfo,
      [teethId]: {
        ...prevInfo[teethId],
        [key]: value
      }
    }));
  }

  return (
    <TeethInfoContext.Provider
      value={{ teethInfo, updateTeethInfo }}
    >
      {children}
    </TeethInfoContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default TeethInfoContext;
```

Of course, you could create a method to modify the complete tooth:

```
function updateCompleteTooth(teethId, newInfo) {
  setTeethInfo(prevInfo => ({
    ...prevInfo,
    [teethId]: newInfo
  }));
}
```